# how to display scrollView already scrolled 20% on startup of activity

Tags: android, android-scrollview

[image]I have made an android activity in that i have put a scrollView,Now i want that when i open the activity,It should alreay scrolled up to 20% ,But it should be scrolled down after that,I have tried so many links and refrences for that,But i am failed to do that,Can anyone please help me how can i do it,My xml code is as below for scrollview,I have put image,I want scrollview show already scrolled to some fixed height on startup of activity.

**main.xml**

```
 <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scr_profile"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollY="200dp"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
......

</ScrollView>
```

Comment: provide a screenshot if possible

Comment: Explain what you have tried. You say you "tried so many links", so you must have tried ScrollView#scrollBy. Why didn't it work for you?

Comment: @Panther-Please see my screenshot dear,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you try Runnable?

```
        final ScrollView scroll = (ScrollView) this.findViewById(R.id.scr_profile);

    scroll.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            scroll.scrollTo(200, 200);
        } 
    });
```

this does work for me.

Comment: Actually ,I have tried this befoe your answer and it worked for me..Thank you dear.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scr_profile"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollY="200dp"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
    <TextView
         android:id="@+id/firstname"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content">


   <requestFocus /> //i put here. you can put on the view where you want to   scroll
   </TextView>
```

......